# WPF Alignment not working

Tags: wpf, alignment

I use the following code in my WPF app, for a groupbox:

```
<GroupBox Style="{StaticResource groupBoxStyle}" Header="RB" Margin="0,6,268,249" Name="groupBoxRB" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="276">
```

This control is within a grid, that is defined like this:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,12,0,12" Name="tabControl1" Background="Transparent">
    <TabItem Style="{StaticResource tabItemMainStyle}" Header="Main" Name="tabItemMain" >
        <Grid Background="Transparent" MinHeight="926" MinWidth="1218">
```

And that tabcontrol is within the main grid:

```
<Window x:Class="SRM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SRM" ResizeMode="CanResize"
        Title="SRM"
        Width="991" Icon="Resources\Icons\SRM.png"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="1024" Height="774" Visibility="Visible" Foreground="#00000000" Margin="0">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource styleBackground}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I don't understand why the groupbox i mentioned won't stretch on its vertical axis... any idea?

Thanks.

PS: the staticresources don't define heights/widths/alignments

Comment: Does your `groupBoxStyle` define a custom ControlTemplate? If so, can we see it?

Comment: Also, is it still a problem if you remove the MinHeight from the inner Grid and the big Margin around the GroupBox?

Comment: groupBoxStyle only defines setters (colors/brushes/opacity).

The margin is so groupboxes don't overlap each others, but it could be replaced if there is something better for that purpose.
Minheight can be removed with no problem.

Comment: what do u mean by the groupboxes don't overlap each others? if the groupboxes reside in a grid you can just control the layout using columns and row so they won't overlap each other, I believe it's the big bottom margin that create this issue.

Comment: @FatalBaboon, have you tried using [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) to see which item isn't stretching (groupbox, grid or tab item)?

Comment: I think dnr3 raised an important issue, the margins seem to be used for layout purpose, and it should not.
I'm gonna rework this with rows and columns.

On a side note, I tried snoop but it doesn't work oO. The tool finds my app but when i try to analyze it nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem came from the designers (vs2010's or blend's) that by default put margins if you place controls manually in them... setting the Margin to 0 solved the problem:

```
<GroupBox Style="{StaticResource groupBoxStyle}" Header="RB" Margin="0" Name="groupBoxRB" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="276">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing something in your styles or something. I just made the following from your code and stretching works fine in standalone app.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,12,0,12" Name="tabControl1" Background="Transparent">
            <TabItem Header="Main" Name="tabItemMain" >
                <Grid Background="Transparent" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="200">
                    <GroupBox Header="RB" Name="groupBoxRB" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="276">
                        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" />
                    </GroupBox>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I think i remember having the same issue some time ago.
From my memory, i noticed that stetching behaviors and the like were messed up whenever i'd take my solution from subversion on a new computer.

Rings any bells?

Comment: Sorry can't say I've encountered that. Could be a default template thing from TabControl or something. One thing to try to would be to set fill colors for each successive UI element so you can figure out the first control that doesn't do stretching properly - that will help sort out which element is the culprit by coloring very clearly what's going on.